# Using hierarchical clustering with an single linkage in R

Tags: r, dataframe, hierarchical-clustering

I am supposed to use Hierarchial clustering with a single linkage in R with the data frame hotels.std

my code:

````
dist_mat = dist(features, method = "euclidean") 
hc_single = hclust(dist_mat, method = "single", members = as.factor(hotels$Hotel_Address))```

my error: 
Error in hclust(dist_mat, method = "single", members = as.factor(hotels$Hotel_Address)) : invalid length of members
````

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question. Either explain clearly what the data is and what you are trying to do or provide a reproducible example.

Comment: From the manual page (`?hclust`): members gives the number of observations per cluster". You are passing a factor. This argument is only used when your dissimilarity matrix is for groups of observations, not individual observations. You seem to be using it a some kind of a label.